# Unable to save to wincache from cakePHP shell

Tags: cakephp, caching

I'm trying to retrieve the weather from wunderground.com through their API, and store it in wincache. For testing purposes I made this function in the News model:

```
public function updateWeather(){
    $results = file_get_contents('http://api.wunderground.com/api/**api_key**/conditions/q/CA/Montreal.json');
    $results = json_decode($results);
    return Cache::write('weather', $results);
}
```

It works fine when I call this from the controller. However, I can't figure why that same function doesn't work when called from the console. I made this shell in order to eventually add this to windows task scheduler.

```
class WeatherShell extends AppShell {
    public $uses = array('News');

    public function main() {
        $this->News->updateWeather();
    }
}
```

When debugging this, I see that $results is correctly populated. I get 'true' from Cache::write(), however, I get 'false' when trying to read.

Cache reading is done at any moment when the following action is called in the news controller

```
public function diaporama(){
    $this->set('weather', Cache::read('weather'));
}
```

This is the cache config I have in bootstrap.php

```
Cache::config('default', array(
    'engine' => 'Wincache',
    'duration'=> 3600,
    'probability'=> 100,
    'prefix' => ''
));
```

Comment: you did not post how you read your cache. maybe the time limit is too short?

Comment: I edited the post to add the reading and config part. As for the time limit, I tried calling cache::read the line following cache::write, so that there should be virtually no delay. I got the same results.

Comment: how do you assert that "even if the cache is not yet generated or outdated" the results are always available? this way it seems you are asking for trouble..

Comment: I plan on asserting that the value exists in diaporama() in the controller. (Is this what you're referring to by 'assert'?) But right now, I thought that simplifying down the problem as much as possible while manually debugging this would be enough to see if I can read/write the cache.